# get total number of tests to be executed in from a spec file

Tags: selenium, protractor, code-coverage

I am new to protractor testing framework. I would like to know if there is a way to dry run protractor config and return the total number of tests cases to be executed on a spec file. (actual execution of test case will not happen now)

Basically, i would like to know number of describe and it test cases available from a *spec.js file. Please can you hint some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this with a custom command line flag, installing jasmin-fail-fast package, and by failing the first test when that flag is passed. But note that there must always be 1 failure.

**Detailed steps**

1. Pass in a custom flag as a command line argument when launching protractor
2. In the onPrepare check if this flag is found
3. If it is then do the next 3 steps:
4. enable the jasmine-fail-fast package (you will need to download with `npm i jasmine-fail-fast --save`
5. Add a custom reporter which only logs number of tests in jasmineStarted lifecycle hook
6. Add beforeAll with a custom fail message

---

**Project structure**
Note the app.1.js and app.2.js are identical so there are 8 specs in total.

[image]

**Command Used**

```
C:\ProtractorProjects\jasmine-test-count>node_modules\.bin\protractor conf.js --params.countSpecs
```

**app.1.js**

```
describe("suite 1", function(){

    it("spec 1", function(){
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });

    it("spec 2", function(){
        expect(true).toBe(false);
    })

    xit("spec 3", function(){
        expect(true).toBe(false);
    })
    xit("spec 4", function(){
        expect(true).toBe(false);
    })
});
```

conf.js

```
exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine',
    specs: "app.*.js",
    onPrepare: function () {

        if (browser.params.countSpecs) {
            //Add jasmine fail fast package
            const failFast = require('jasmine-fail-fast');
            jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(failFast.init());

            //Add custom reporter which only counts 
            jasmine.getEnv().addReporter({
                jasmineStarted: function (suiteInfo) {
                    console.log(`Due to execute #${suiteInfo.totalSpecsDefined} specs in total`);
                }
            });

            beforeAll(function () {
                fail("Failing because only a count was required");
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Output
[image]

Comment: Glad to hear it @stevaa123. Would you mind accepting this answer when you get a chance so that other people searching in future that there is a working solution.

Comment: Also be aware that the final count number will include specs which have been skipped by marking as `xit`. You can see this in my app.1.js